# WordPress Creating Empty database

Tags: database, wordpress, apache, wamp, port

WordPress Creating Empty database. (there is a database but with out any values!)

I am on local WAMP Server 2.4 (PHP 5.4)
Windows 8
WordPress 3.6 (also tried 3.5.1)

Wamp Apache is Giving some errors I am pasting few lines here:

### access.log:

```
"GET /test_3/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.min.css?ver=3.6 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
"GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?db=db_test_3&token=4bb71407ccf91fc27d3c8338186ee369&db=db_test_3&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&menuHashes=572d5b14-cb7c7ed1-ada592ed-4fce1948&_nocache=1376960501429607598 HTTP/1.1" 200 40875
```

### apache_error.log

```
[Mon Aug 19 13:34:54.335301 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7864:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6540
[Mon Aug 19 13:34:54.769224 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6540:tid 344] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 19 18:09:28.498364 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7864:tid 468] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
```

**Possibly related to issue:** I have changed port to :8080 cuz windows 8 was already using port :80

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: Nop!, no erros in PHP log.

Comment: Research in [sf] and [su].

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo didn't found related post but i have posted question there as well in hope to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! -- i might have messed this up while changing port.

### In httpd.conf -- i had this:

```
Listen 8080
#Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

### Simply changed it to this:

```
#Listen 8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Database was receiving values but word-press started giving this error on loin attempt

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page
```

So i simply went to database and gave my user administrator privileges! ([From here](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database) i followed the instruction under heading "Editing the wp_usermeta table")